# How to add jquery ui sortable property in dymic ng-repeat of Angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have some list, and I make the list sortable with the following code:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="groupNo in tempGroupList | filter:{groupNumber: selectedGroupNo}" data-ng-show="subGroupFound==false" >
                <ul data-ng-repeat="group in groupNo.groupMembers track by group.id"   id="sortable"  class="connectedSortable">
                    <li class="ui-state-default" id="{{group.id}}">
                        <div>
                            {{group.programName}}:{{group.year}}/{{group.semester}} ({{group.studentNumber}})
                        </div>
                        <div data-ng-show="group.showSubPortion">
                            <hr>
                            Split size: <input  data-ng-model="splitNumber" style="width:40px;color: black "  />
                            <button data-ng-click="splitAction(splitNumber)" style="color: black">Split</button><button data-ng-click="cancelSplitAction()" style="color: black">cancel</button>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Well, the sortable functionality works. But, in my code, in the second div (subPortion), there is an option to split the number of students the list have. The user will right click on the list and enter a number to split. After the split, I want to update the list, and want to add the splitted list at the top. But, my problem is, the list is updated when one is splitted. But, when I add the splitted portion at the top, the portion is shown, but, is not sortable.How can I make the splitted portion sortable. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?\

Comment: I just want to make the list sortable, whever the list is updated...ng-repeat shows the updated list, but, the updated items are not sortable.

Comment: you need to call sortable again to the updated list

Comment: You have to do that in a directive definitions.

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried calling the sortable by  $("sortable").sortable(); but, no result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ui-sortable](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-sortable/) library developed by Angular UI team. It is based on jquery UI sortable and is created to work with dynamic elements created by AngularJS `ngRepeat`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to do some DOM changes then you have to do that in the directive definition object's link function:

```
<div data-sortable-parent
     data-ng-repeat="groupNo in tempGroupList | filter:{groupNumber: selectedGroupNo}" 
     data-ng-show="subGroupFound==false" >
```

Now the DDO *(Directive Definition Object)*:

```js
theApp.directive('sortableParent', function(){
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link:function(scope, el, attrs){
         el.find('ul').sortable(); // <---apply sortable here.
     }
   };
});
```